# sending wso2am logs to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, wso2-api-manager, filebeat

i want to send my wso2am logs to elasticsearch. i've searched and found out in order to do that i have to use filebeat. but i don't know how to config my filebeat.yml. any idea how to config filebeat.yam?

Comment: You can find a sample here - https://github.com/pubudu538/demos/tree/master/S13-Deploy_ELK_with_Filebeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to provide a custom `file` input for this, as there is no existing module

check out https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html and then https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-filestream.html